# Django RunTime Warning due to receiving a native DateTime. How to solve?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

In my settings.py TIME_ZONE is set to 'UTC'.

In one of my models I'm importing the `created_on` field from an external API which returns time in utc format. For eg: `1515374422.0` To convert that into DateTime format I use:

```
created_on=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1515374422.0))
post=Post(name="ABC", created_on=created_on)
```

But that always runs with a RunTime warning of:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Image.added_on received a naive datetime
>   (2017-12-14 14:48:22) while time zone support is active.

I don't understand it. What does that mean? Is something wrong with the DateTime conversion code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the django orm expects all `datetime` objects to have the timezone set.  For your code, since you know the timezone is coming in as UTC, you can simply do the following:

```
import pytz
created_on=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1515374422.0))
created_on = created_on.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
post=Post(name="ABC", created_on=created_on)
```

The additional line will add the timezone information for created on so that you are explicitly asking for a `datetime` in UTC.

Comment: Perfect. That worked. I thought tzinfo would be added in by default according to my timezone setting..